# Vuetify `v-file-input` submits file immediately after file is selected instead of after hitting submit

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I have a Vue component that captures a file input from the user. I want the file input to open a file browser where the user can select a valid file type and then display that file as the selected file as a chip. When the user clicks on `submit`, I want the axios call to be made to submit the file to the backend.

The problem is that as soon as the file is selected from the file browser, the axios call is made -- without the user clicking submit. I am still learning how to set up a dummy project in Codepen. My application does run the component properly though.

```js
import { store, mutations } from "../../store.js"
import * as vuetify from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/vuetify@2.4.3";
import * as axios from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/axios@0.21.1";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      upDocs: '',
      files: [],
      file: '',
      formData: new FormData()
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    submitFile() {
      var FormData = require('form-data');
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('File', this.file);
      
      var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://someServer.com:8101/path/to/controller',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        data : data
      };
      
      axios(config)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
    }
  }
  
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/infinity-1/pen/NWbKmwW?editors=1111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to bind a `click`-handler with [`v-bind` shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) like this:

```html
<v-btn :click="submitFile()">
```

That's actually binding a property named `click` to the result of `submitFile()` (the method is invoked immediately).

You probably meant to use [`v-on` shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand) like this:

```html
<v-btn @click="submitFile()">

<!-- or -->
<v-btn @click="submitFile">
```